# C shell remove line from file

Tags: csh

I have a file output.txt. File looks like this:

```
name1 10
name2 12
name3 5
```

I get a number n and I need to remove all lines which have number (after name) smaller or equal to number n.

Comment: Did you try to make a script yourself? If so, what does that look like? In addition, csh is not a very good programming tool and has a lot of serious limitations. I would not recommend using it for new scripts.

Comment: Do you need to use CSH for this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/csh
set CMPNUM = 5
set FILE = output.txt

set TMPFILE = ( `mktemp` )
# read in
foreach line ( "`cat $FILE`" )
  set argv = ( $line )
  set STR = $1
  set NUM = $2

  if ( `echo "$NUM > $CMPNUM" | bc` ) then
    echo "$STR $NUM" >> $TMPFILE
  endif
end
mv $TMPFILE $FILE
```

Comment: I need C shell. I do not know bash